# how to run sql query regarding innerjoin

Tags: sql, inner-join

```
select rm_id as 'ID'
        bk_branch as 'BRANCH'
        br_name as 'BANK REP.'
        bs_name as 'ESCORT'
        dt_rep  as 'DATE'
        rep_time as 'TIME'
        amt
        inv_no
        total_box
        box_no
        note_state
        dm_state
        1
        2
        10
        20
        50
        100
        500
        1000
        tp
        tv
        tp_ex1
        tv_ex1
        tp_m
        tv_m         
from bk_det 
inner join bk_rep 
  on bk_det.rm_id =  bk_rep.rm_id
inner join bk_sec 
  on bk_rep.rm_id = bk_sec.rm_id
inner join mut_det 
  on bk_sec.rm_id =  mut_det.rm_id
inner join rm_det 
  on mut_det.rm_id = rm_det.rm_id
inner join soil_det 
    on rm_det.rm_id = soil_det.rm_id
```

I have written the code above from my table but not running its showing error:

> *Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>
>   Incorrect syntax near 'bk_branch'.*

please help..!!

Comment: You need to have **commas** `,` after every column you select !!

Comment: It's a little confusing that the syntax checker stops on the first error. Of course, there are many errors, and seeing that might have helped you identify the pattern. One way to diagnose this might have been to remove the JOINs. Your select on one table would not have worked. Start with a simple SQL statement, and only add to it when it works. Then, when it breaks, you know where the problem lies.

Comment: In addition to commas, you should get into the habit of putting aliases before every column reference.  `rm_id` for one is ambiguous, so it will generate an error.  You need something like `bk_det.rm_id`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to separate the fields in the `SELECT` by `,`s. The joins themselves look OK syntactically.

```
select rm_id as 'ID'
        ,bk_branch as 'BRANCH'
        ,br_name as 'BANK REP.'
        ,bs_name as 'ESCORT'
        ,dt_rep  as 'DATE'
        ,rep_time as 'TIME'
        ,amt
        ,inv_no
        ,total_box
        ,box_no
        ,note_state
        ,dm_state
        ,1
        ,2
        ,10
        ,20
        ,50
        ,100
        ,500
        ,1000
        ,tp
        ,tv
        ,tp_ex1
        ,tv_ex1
        ,tp_m
        ,tv_m         
from bk_det 
...
```

Comment: Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ambiguous column name 'rm_id'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Ambiguous column name 'dt_rep'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Ambiguous column name 'rep_time'.

Comment: it is showing above error again..!!

Comment: @user1904521 - Different error. You are selecting a column with a name that appears in more than one table. You need to qualify such columns with the table name that you want it to be selected from - `<table name>.<column name>`.

Comment: Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ambiguous column name 'rm_id'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Ambiguous column name 'dt_rep'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Ambiguous column name 'rep_time'.
now it is showing above error..!!

Comment: @user1904521 - Yes. It is essentially the same issue. Can you not read the error message and understand what it means? It says what the problem is and even tells you what column is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

just give the table aliases to the columns other wise it 'll give ambiguity.

```
select a.rm_id as 'ID',
        bk_branch as 'BRANCH',
        br_name as 'BANK REP.', 
        bs_name as 'ESCORT',
        dt_rep  as 'DATE',
        rep_time as 'TIME',
        amt,
        inv_no,
        total_box,
        box_no,
        note_state,
        dm_state,
        1 ,
        2,
        10,
        20,
        50,
        100,
        500,
        1000,
        tp,
        tv,
        tp_ex1,
        tv_ex1,
        tp_m,
        tv_m,         
from bk_det a
inner join bk_rep b
  on a.rm_id =  b.rm_id
inner join bk_sec c 
  on b.rm_id = c.rm_id
inner join mut_det d
  on c.rm_id =  d.rm_id
inner join rm_det e
  on d.rm_id = e.rm_id
inner join soil_det f
    on e.rm_id = f.rm_id;
```